# jQuery- only listen to scroll if certain element is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I only want to listen to the scroll event if the button with the class name "scroll_button" is displayed. I want to save resources. How can I achieve it?

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

});
```

HTML

```
<button class="scroll_button" style="display: none;"> click here </button>
```

Comment: Just a little workaround: Why not always listening to the scroll and eventually act if the button is displayed?

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You have no control over the code that changes the display of the button…?

Comment: @TJ it appears after a user clicked another button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments, since the button's visibility is controlled by another button, you can do this:

```
$("#change").click(function () { // button that controls visibility

  $(".scroll_button").toggle(0, function () { 
    if ($(".scroll_button").is(':visible')) {
        $(window).on("scroll", function (e) { // listen to scroll
            console.log("scolling");
        });
    } else {
        $(window).off("scroll"); // stop listening to scroll
    }
  });

});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/77pyzry3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if( $('.scroll_button').css('display') != 'none' )
  {
    //do something
  }
});
```

Comment: but this way it will always listen to scroll, even if it is not needed

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Event listeners that act on elements greater than sub elements cannot be made dependent on sub elements.

But you can listen to all scroll events and in the callback check for the display state of the button like this: http://jsfiddle.net/db27hzwk/

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    if($(".scroll-button").is(':visible')) {
        console.log("business logic");
    };
});
```

Comment: but this way it will always listen to scroll, even if it is not needed

Comment: @user2952265 This is correct, Sir. But unfortunately it is not possible otherwise using jQuery or plain Javascript.